# Laravel API endpoint not working on remote server

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I have Laravel installed on my local machine and on a remote test server. The regular web pages are working fine on both systems. I also have an API endpoint which dumps some data in JSON format. It is working perfectly fine on my computer:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/GetData
```

However, when I visit this link in a browser, the page does not load up (The requested URL could not be found):

```
myServer.com/api/GetData
```

What could be the reason? The routes to the API are defined in my api.php file

EDIT:
*I found the issue: The project is installed under a projectName dir on the remote server: myServer.com/projectName/ . I was able to access the api endpoint by visiting: `myServer.com/projectName/public/api/GetData`*

New question: why does **myServer.com/projectName/api/getData** not work?

Comment: your server is probably not setup correctly

Comment: Can you please be more specific? The server is serving 'regular' web pages defined in the web.php routes.

Comment: content-type= application/json set in the header in Postman?